# Let $F$ be a field with characteristic 0, and $p(x)\in F[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree 3 with root $\alpha$. Show $F(\alpha)=F(\alpha^2)$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I think I have a solution for this, but I have doubts for its validity:
We immediately see that $F(\alpha^2)\subseteq F(\alpha)$. Well, in the language of Galois theory, $F(\alpha^2)$ is either an intermediate field or is equal to $F(\alpha)$.

Suppose $F(\alpha^2)$ is an intermediate field in the lattice for the splitting field of $p(x)$. This means there exists a subgroup of automorphisms in $Gal(F, F[x]/(p(x))$ such that $F(\alpha^2)$ is fixed. Let $\sigma$ be one such automorphism. Then, as $F(\alpha^2)$ is fixed, $\sigma(\alpha^2)=\sigma(\alpha)\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha^2$, so $\sigma(\alpha)=\pm \alpha$. If $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha$, then $\alpha$ would also be fixed,

However, the roots of $p(x)$ must be $\alpha, \omega\alpha, \omega^2\alpha$, where $\omega$ is the traditional cube root of unity. Since elements of the Galois group must send roots of the polynomial to other roots, $\sigma(\alpha)\not=-\alpha$, so $\alpha$ must be fixed by all automorphisms that fix $\alpha^2$, and $F(\alpha)=F(\alpha^2)$.

My doubts are in a few parts: I did not use the characteristic 0 requirement. Is this just necessary background machinery for the Galois theorems? Also, my claim that elements of the Galois group may only permute roots of that splitting field, is that always true (in the case of the splitting field of the polynomial)?

Comment: $\alpha^3+A\alpha^2+B\alpha+C=0\implies \alpha=-\frac {A\alpha^2+C}{\alpha^2+B}$.  The case $\alpha^2=-B$ can be ruled out (why?)

Comment: Should have said:  I can't follow your argument.  You appear to be assuming that $p(x)=x^3-c$ for some $c\in \mathbb F$, but not all cubics are of that form.

Comment: @lulu I was under the belief that -all- cube roots could be found by multiplying by the primitive cube roots, which I see now that is only true in that case you mentioned, thank you very much!
I am trying to wrap my head around your first comment a bit, do you mean $\alpha^2=-\alpha$? can be ruled out?

Comment: No, I meant that $\alpha^2+B=0$ can be ruled out.  If it couldn't, then my formula would have a problem in that case (as you can not divide by $0$).  But since it can be ruled out, the formula shows that $\alpha\in \mathbb F(\alpha^2)$ as desired.

Comment: @lulu oh wow, yes I knew why that is ruled out, but I totally missed why that helped us, but I see know you wrote $\alpha$ in terms of elements in $F(\alpha^2)$. Sorry for missing that.
I would like to ask how you thought to come up with the formula for $\alpha$, I would not at all of thought to have done that, or that I even could write it in terms of $\alpha^2$.

Comment: If $\alpha \in \mathbb F(\alpha^2)$ then there must be an expression like that (that's what it means for $\alpha$ to be in that field).  And, given that the only thing we know about $\alpha$ is that it satisfies some cubic over the base field the expression must derive from that.

Comment: To clarify your understanding, try to work through why an argument parallel to mine fails if $\alpha$ is the root of an irreducible quartic.

Comment: @lulu in that case, solving for $\alpha$ gives $\alpha=-\frac{A\alpha^3+B\alpha^2}{\alpha^3+C}$, and, while we know $\alpha^3=-C$ implies our polynomial would be reducible which it can't be, so this is defined, our fraction is in terms of $\alpha^2$ and $\alpha^3$, which does not help us, as having those elements in the field would have already implied we had $\alpha$. Is this right?

Comment: No.  If $\alpha^4+A\alpha^3+B\alpha^2+C\alpha+D=0$ then $\alpha=-\frac {\alpha^4+B\alpha^2+D}{A\alpha^2+C}$ which almost works but there is no reason  why we couldn't have $(A,C)=(0,0)$ and in that case, the formula fails.

Comment: @lulu then maybe I don't understand the original argument, you said $\alpha^2\not=-B$. I thought this was because an irreducible cubic cannot have a square root as a root, which I tried to make analogous to my other argument. So, I suppose I don't know why this cannot be the case.

Comment: If $\alpha^2+B=0$ then the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ would have degree $1$ or $2$, but we know it has degree $3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You took it a bit too far, this problem doesn't require any use of automorphisms. We have $[F(\alpha):F]=3$. By the tower rule:

$3=[F(\alpha):F]=[F(\alpha):F(\alpha^2)]\cdot [F(\alpha^2):F].$

And so either $F(\alpha^2)=F(\alpha)$ or $F(\alpha^2)=F$. Assume the latter is true. Then $\alpha^2\in F$, and hence $\alpha$ is a root of the polynomial $x^2-\alpha^2\in F[x]$. But this is a contradiction, because the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$ has degree $3$. So we must have $F(\alpha^2)=F(\alpha)$. The characteristic of $F$ doesn't matter.

Comment: I wanted to use that rule, but I didn't think that we could automatically say that was degree 3.
I have my doubts about why we do get to automatically say that, but is it because we are an irreducible polynomial? I am not sure how to make that argument there.
Past that, this is very nice, thank you!

Comment: @cable The extension degree $[F(\alpha):F]$ is equal to the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$. (if $\alpha$ is algebraic, of course) It is a simple exercise that if $f\in F[x]$ is monic, irreducible, and $f(\alpha)=0$, then $f$ must be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. This just follows from the fact that the minimal polynomial divides $f$, and since $f$ is irreducible and monic, the two polynomials must be equal.

Comment: Ah, yes that is horribly clear then. I was conflating this with something like the degree of the splitting field over F, which I know has some degree of variance, but that is an entirely different question. Perfect! Thank you so much